# Problems w/ Visual Source Safe 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe

my team recently moved to Visual Source Safe 2005 from VSS6 (since we migrated to Windows 7) and we've been seeing intermittent problems of files disappearing.

Does anyone know what may cause this to occur? We have a team in the US, but also a development team in India, and we access the same files... From what my developers say, it's only occurring on the files that are shared by both teams. I know there was a timezone issue with VSS2005, but I'm not sure what would solve it.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Do the disappeared files come back later? You can run VSS Analyzer to see whether it helps.

Comment: No, they don't appear to come back later. Running the Analyzer and Repair doesn't seem to fix it as it's always saying I need to run the Analyzer. I suppose I'll need to accelerate our migration to TFS :-P. Sorry I couldn't identify a better solution. Some people suspected it might be due to an offshore team checking in files and their time zone difference causing VSS to be confused with checkins from the future...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing files disappear **because you're using Visual SourceSafe**.

See [Source Control: Anything but SourceSafe](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/source-control-anything-but-sourcesafe.html). You'll be glad you did. There's no excuse to still be using VSS today.